# display: none & setAttribute() not working

Tags: javascript, css

Simply changing an attribute on `.p-header` in `.css`from,
`display: 'none'`.
to 
`display:'block'`
using JS.

I've check chrome tools before execution and `display:'none'`is not shown in the the `html`.

Yet the tag it's in, is not showing, like `display,'none'`is meant for.

After running script `display: 'block'` appears dynamically via `.js` in the `html`. But nothing appears on screen

`html`

```
<header>
        <h1>Take the Dog Quiz</h1>
        <p class="p-header">You scored: <span class="p-span"></span></p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form action="#">
            <div class="q1-div">
                <h5>Can dogs run?</h5><br>
                <label for="q1" id="q1">Yes.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="a" checked><br>
                <label for="q1">No.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="b">
            </div>

            <div class="q2-div">
                <h5>Are dogs invisible?</h5><br>
                <label for="q2">Yes.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="a" checked><br>
                <label for="q2">No.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="b">
            </div>

            <div class="q3-div">
                <h5>Does a dog have 4 legs?</h5><br>
                <label for="q3">Yes.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="a" checked><br>
                <label for="q3">No.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="b">
            </div>

            <div class="q4-div">
                <h5>Can a dog fly?</h5>
                <label for="q4">Yes.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4" value="a" checked><br>
                <label for="q4">No.</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="q4" id="q4" value="b">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </main>


    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

`Css`

```
.p-header{
    display: none;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

```js``

```
const answers = ['a','b','a','b'];
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const p = document.querySelector('.p-span');
const phead = document.querySelector('.p-header');

//add event listener to form
form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //remove display: none from css script to block
    phead.setAttribute('display', 'block');
    scrollTo(0,0);

    let score = 0;
    //collect user answers
    const attemptedAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value,form.q3.value,form.q4.value];

    //loop and compare user answers to correct "answers".
    //increase score total per correct answer
    attemptedAnswers.forEach((answer, index) =>{
        if(answer === answers[index]){
            score += 25;
        }
    });

    //display animation of score with setInterval then stop interval when counter === score
    let counter = 0;
    const scoreboard = setInterval(()=>{

        p.textContent = `${counter}%`;

        if(counter === score){
            clearInterval(scoreboard);
        }
        console.log(counter);
        counter ++;
    }, 10);


});
```

Comment: display is not an attribute , you should use phead.style.display='block'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'display' is not an attribute of html element.
 'style' is an attribute.

Both of these would work -

> phead.style.display = 'block';
>
> phead.style.setProperty('display', 'block');

Explaination -
display is a property of style. style is an attribute of html element.